# BLE telemetry data via thingsboard-gateway is not updating in thingsboard

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I tried everywhere for a solution but I'm stuck.

My setup is the following:

ESP32 uses BLE GATT NOTIFICATION characteristic to push temperature data via thingsboard gateway into thingsboard. Once the BLE connection is established the first telemetry package is shown in the freshly created device's 'latest telemetry' area. If i turn on gateway debugging I can see further notifications reaching thingboard like this:

`{"LOGS":"2020-07-20 02:04:19,640 - DEBUG - [ble_connector.py] - ble_connector - 321 - Notification received from device {'device_config': {'name': 'Esp32 v2.2', 'MACAddress': '24:62:AB:F3:43:72', 'telemetry': [{'key': 'temperature', 'method': 'notify', 'characteristicUUID': '0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91', 'byteFrom': 0, 'byteTo': -1}], 'attributes': [{'key': 'name', 'characteristicUUID': '00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB', 'method': 'read', 'byteFrom': 0, 'byteTo': -1}], 'attributeUpdates': [{'attributeOnThingsBoard': 'sharedName', 'characteristicUUID': '00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB'}], 'serverSideRpc': [{'methodRPC': 'rpcMethod1', 'withResponse': True, 'characteristicUUID': '00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB', 'methodProcessing': 'read'}]}, 'interest_uuid': {'00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': [{'section_config': {'key': 'name', 'characteristicUUID': '00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB', 'method': 'read', 'byteFrom': 0, 'byteTo': -1}, 'type': 'attributes', 'converter': <thingsboard_gateway.connectors.ble.bytes_ble_uplink_converter.BytesBLEUplinkConverter object at 0xb4427eb0>}], '0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91': [{'section_config': {'key': 'temperature', 'method': 'notify', 'characteristicUUID': '0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91', 'byteFrom': 0, 'byteTo': -1}, 'type': 'telemetry', 'converter': <thingsboard_gateway.connectors.ble.bytes_ble_uplink_converter.BytesBLEUplinkConverter object at 0xb4427eb0>}]}, 'scanned_device': <bluepy.btle.ScanEntry object at 0xb443a290>, 'is_new_device': False, 'peripheral': <bluepy.btle.Peripheral object at 0xb58f0070>, 'services': {'00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'00002A05-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a210>, 'handle': 2}}, '00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a270>, 'handle': 21}, '00002A01-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a1d0>, 'handle': 23}, '00002AA6-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a2b0>, 'handle': 25}}, 'AB0828B1-198E-4351-B779-901FA0E0371E': {'0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a6b0>, 'handle': 41}, '4AC8A682-9736-4E5D-932B-E9B31405049C': {'characteristic': <bluepy.btle.Characteristic object at 0xb443a5f0>, 'handle': 44}}}} handle: 42, data: b'25.00'"}` 
the data i would like to update is the string '25.00'

I know I could update thingsboard directly but is the use of BLE that I'm interested in because I like that the sensors are notwork agnostic.

My question is why the updated temperature, even if reaching thingsboard won't show up and what can I change in order to make it happen.

Any kind of help much appreciated. I've being wrestling with this the entire weekend.

Adding more clarifications:
ESP32 code generate the BLE notifications: https://pastebin.com/NqMfxsK6

```
{
    "name": "BLE Connector",
    "rescanIntervalSeconds": 100,
    "checkIntervalSeconds": 10,
    "scanTimeSeconds": 5,
    "passiveScanMode": true,
    "devices": [
        {
            "name": "Temperature and humidity sensor",
            "MACAddress": "24:62:AB:F3:43:72",
            "telemetry": [
                {
                    "key": "temperature",
                    "method": "notify",
                    "characteristicUUID": "0972EF8C-7613-4075-AD52-756F33D4DA91",
                    "byteFrom": 0,
                    "byteTo": -1
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "name",
                    "characteristicUUID": "00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB",
                    "method": "read",
                    "byteFrom": 0,
                    "byteTo": -1
                }
            ],
            "attributeUpdates": [
                {
                    "attributeOnThingsBoard": "sharedName",
                    "characteristicUUID": "00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"
                }
            ]
        }


    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question lacks clarity and it is therefore, very unlikely you'll get an answer. Please update your question with code that you tried. Explain exactly what's not working (e.g. error codes and descriptions) and which line(s) are causing these errors. Once there's enough information, people here will only be glad to help.

Comment: The log contains all the data needed to at least give an indication where the problem lies. The log shows how the data arrives into a framework. It's a clear indication of its source and value. My question Is not about programming , it's about configuration, since data arrives. Everything else is redundant, though I've pasted. Even if its my first post I've being a long time user and the reason I haven't posted yet is because I've managed to get the answers.  The question is very specific and only those people accustomed with thingsboard in particular could know an answer.

Comment: I'd love to know more about why my question lacks clarity, please do elaborate.